# HTML when downloaded with "Save As" slightly different than HTML downloaded using Python Requests

Tags: python, html, python-requests, urllib

I've using Beautiful Soup and Requests to webscrape a table, and to test I've downloaded a webpage by right-clicking and using "Save As" to download a full HTML file. But when I tested my webscraper against the actual website, the output was slightly off. So I used Requests to download the page into another html file using this code:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("URL")
with open('page_content.html', 'w') as fid:
    fid.write(r.text)
fid.close()
```

And noticed that the relevant parts I wanted to webscrape (the table) were the same up to a few unclosed tags. The Save As html page had correctly closed tags, but the Requests page is missing the ends of some tags. For example, the Save As doc has all its tags closed:

```
<td>
    <td>stuff</td>
</td>
```

But the Requests downloaded doc is missing some of the closing tags:

```
<td>
   <td>stuff
</td>
```

The site itself appears correctly formatted, and when I use Inspect, all the tags are closed. But when when I use View Page Source, I see the missing tags. The Requests-downloaded page shows up correctly formatted when opened in Chrome.

This is causing me some trouble when trying to use BeautifulSoup to parse the data.

How can I get the HTML doc with the correctly closed tags without going in and right-click-downloading each page I want?

Comment: You are confusing the view on the DOM (the browsers interpretation of the HTML) with the original HTML.

Answer (score 0):

In web development, "tag soup" is a pejorative term that refers to syntactically or structurally incorrect HTML written for a web page.

web browsers has its own parser which correct a missing html tags, fortunately beautiful soup has `html5lib` parser which can do this job as well.

Quted from bs4 official docs:

> Here’s the a document parsed using html5lib

```
BeautifulSoup("<a></p>", "html5lib")
# <html><head></head><body><a><p></p></a></body></html>
# Instead of ignoring the dangling </p> tag, html5lib pairs it with an opening <p> tag.
```

> This parser also adds an empty  tag to the document.
>
> Here’s the same document parsed with Python’s built-in HTML parser:

```
BeautifulSoup("<a></p>", "html.parser")
# <a></a>
```

further reading and references:
[bs4-difference between parsers](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers), 
[wikipedia tag soup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_soup)